# ARIMA training super slow

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, arima

I am fitting ARIMA model (from statsmodels) on 20 000 elements dataset on a 24 CPU 200+GB RAM cloud server for over 24 hours now. It loads all the CPU's. But It takes so long... Is it how it works or is here something wrong?

p,d,q are just numbers

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(p, d, q))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=1)
    output = model_fit.forecast()
    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)obs = test[t]
    history.append(obs)
```

Comment: can you give more details on your code implementation? are you carrying out hyperparametrization of p, d, q params or just with a fixed set of hyperparams?

Comment: your code implementation seems ok to me at a first glance; a possible check I can think of is to try the same code on a small sample of your dataset (not the whole 20k samples), to validate that it is not a code (or dataset) problem; on the other hand, in case it is a performance related problem, you can also make time series forecast with tensorflow keras (which I can give you some examples if interested)

Comment: thank you, please give me some examples

Comment: ok I'll post a worked put example later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find below a worked out example (on a univariate version for the temperatures attribute) which, using statsmodels ARIMA, does not even finish the excution after hours trying for it.

An option you have regarding the performance issues is to actually use another efficient library like Keras with Tensorflow modelling an LSTM useful for time series data, which is capable of dealing with so many samples without performance issues.

This dataset contains 420551 samples, which is very costly with the ARIMA statsmodels approach via walk-forward validation...
You can extract the temperature values for carrying out the univariate time series forecast.

See below an example (based on [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series)) where leaving hyperparametrization aside for now, you can train a nearly half a millon time series samples without performance issues (you can try on google colab for faster checks for free).
From the example in the tutorial, you should pay special attention at:

- the way the data is splitted:

def univariate_data(dataset, start_index, end_index, history_size, target_size):

```
data = []
labels = []

start_index = start_index + history_size
if end_index is None:
  end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

for i in range(start_index, end_index):
  indices = range(i-history_size, i)
  #### Reshape data from (history_size,) to (history_size, 1)
  data.append(np.reshape(dataset[indices], (history_size, 1)))
  labels.append(dataset[i+target_size])

return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

where, using 20 samples as recent history to predict the next value you can use:

```
univariate_past_history = 20
univariate_future_target = 0

x_train_uni, y_train_uni = univariate_data(uni_data, 0, TRAIN_SPLIT,
                                       univariate_past_history,
                                       univariate_future_target)
x_val_uni, y_val_uni = univariate_data(uni_data, TRAIN_SPLIT, None,
                                   univariate_past_history,
                                   univariate_future_target)
```

having something like:

[image]

- the way the model is defined:

  simple_lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8, input_shape=x_train_uni.shape[-2:]),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
  ])

which comparing to a baseline model by predicting simply the mean of the history values, you have:

- baseline model predicting based on simply the mean of past values:
  [image]

### VS

- predicting wih the trained LSTM model:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!